# What is the [l-moment] tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed today that we have a tag for [l-moments](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l-moments) without a description. For once, this isn't my fault. I hope that by bringing it to the attention of meta readers, we could create one. (I don't know anything about l-moments.)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment ?

Comment: It looks like this tag was created by @Kjetilbhalvorsen. He may be able to provide the most appropriate excerpt.

Comment: No problem. This is just about keeping Meta tidy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following @gung's comment above, I pinged @Kjetil and asked to provide a wiki excerpt. He kindly agreed, and so here is the new excerpt:

> A kind of moments based on linear functions of order statistics. Their interpretation is similar to usual moments, but they can often be more stably estimated.

and wiki:

> L-moments are a kind of moments based on linear functions of order statistics. Their interpretation is similar to usual moments, but they can often be more stably estimated.
>
> Their use was pioneered in hydrology, as a help in studying the form of probability distributions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment.

Comment: (+1) Too bad the tags cannot have upper-case letters (or serif fonts). I just hope we never have to compute L-moments for [moments of intertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia) $I$!